# Unable to populate a field w/ data containing &#039; (single quote, apostrophe) in JavaScript w/ Laravel and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5, single-quotes

I am trying to populate a form field with some data from a database that contains a single quote.  The data was stored in a MySQL database with PHP (and Laravel) using htmlentities() with the ENT_QUOTES option and I confirmed that the single quotes are converted to `&#039;` when saved in the database.

I can display this with no issues on my PHP page by echoing it out, but when I try to use javascript or jquery to populate the field, it does not work.  I have tried .replace to substitute the `&#039;` with `\'` to escape the quote but I still had no luck.  The field is called "note" and here is the relevant code, where $data represents the data as retrieved from the database:

```
<?php $data = "&#039;Twas The Night Before Christmas"; ?>
<form method="post" name="my_form">
  <input type="text" name="note" id="note" value="" /> 
  <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editNote('<?php echo $data; ?>')" />
  <!-- other elements here ... --> 
</form>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
//I have tried:
function editNote(data){
    $('#note').val(data);
}

//I also tried:
function editNote(note){
    var form = document.getElementById('my_form');
    form.note.value = data.replace(/&#039;/g, "\\'");
}
```

I also tried using PHP's addslashes() in my javascript call but that did not work either.  I'm not sure why, but any data with `&#039;` is not escaped properly and so my field is not being populated.  Data without single quotes is fine.  Data with double quotes using `&quot;` is also fine.  So now I'm stumped and I figured I'd reach out to the community for guidance.  Any ideas as to what could be the cause?  Did I miss something trivial?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php $data = "&#039;Twas The Night Before Christmas"; ?>
<form method="post" name="my_form">
  <input type="text" name="note" id="note" value="" /> 
  <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick='editNote("<?php echo $data; ?>")' />
  <!-- other elements here ... --> 
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function editNote(data){
    $('#note').val(data);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, but I found that the following solution is what worked.  I simply used PHP's str_replace to replace the `&#039;` with an escaped single quote `\'` as follows:

```
editNote('<?php echo str_replace("&#039;", "\'",$data); ?>')
```